# Changing default validation messages

Tags: validation, eclipse-emf

Using EMF Validation to validate model I get error messages such as

> The feature 'blah' of 'blah' with 0 values must have at least 1 values

This message might be confusing to user, is there anyway I can override this error message for particular element/attribute with custom message? In a schema perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have done this by adding a new fragment for `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` with our new message texts in the file `plugin_en.properties`. These will take precedence over the texts in `plugin.properties`...

Comment: @pasemes [Sorry for the late answer] have a look at the existing `plugin.properties` in the plugin `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` - you can unpack it using Import with sources in the Plugins view.